# Does a node app work after I hibernate my laptop

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I use forever npm to run my node apps. I executed: "forever start index.js" and left VSCode. I hibernated the computer then. I didn't have a 2nd device to test if my node app still works. Btw it is a discord bot. not really a node app tho

Comment: Generally, no. If your computer goes to sleep it probably doesn't serve any requests anymore.

Comment: So do you recommend a VPS or something?

Comment: If you want to run a service at all times, and you don't have a computer that can stay on, then yes.. you will need to pay for hosting somewhere.